# Use a host machine's packages from guest chroot in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, chroot

I am testing my software's compatibility with a very old version of Ubuntu. The software until now was developed on Ubuntu Precise 12.04 and now need to be tested on Ubuntu 6.0 Dapper.

For this I installed Dapper as chroot inside my Precise. The software is supposed to be built from source. It has to be compiled with libc6-2.3 which is available on chroot's dapper.

Since all the other major dependencies are already installed on the host machine (Precise), I want those installations to be used right away. I do not want to install them all again on Dapper. However libc6-2.3 must be used from Dapper only.

My questions:

1. Is this possible at all?
2. If yes, how? What I understand here is that I cannot things like: `"mount --bind /etc <chroot dir>/etc"`. If I do this it would be just like building my software on Precise itself, right?

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, it may be easier to try out the os in a virtual machine. Otherwise the dependencies from your machine will start messing it around - they'll have had a lot of changes in 6 years! Grab a copy of virtalbox and install within that.

As for the chroot binding, its probably possible but not a good idea. Get a VM and testing will be easier :)